# How to get a list of elements out of a list based on conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I want to pick elements out of a list based on if the elements in another list.

```
list1 = List<FileModel>(){..};
List2 = List<WindowModel>(){...};

List3 = List1.Where(d => List2.Select(x => x.FileName).Contains(d.FileName));
```

But I've got an error (Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<> to System.Collections.Generic.List<>).  How to get it done here?

Comment: Please post your error info ? as well as what are you expecting

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: How is `List3` declared? If it is a `List<FileModel>`, you can convert the `IEnumberable<FileModel>` thats the result of the `Where` by adding `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: please check with  ToList()   List1.Where(d => List2.Select(x => x.FileName).Contains(d.FileName)).ToList();

Comment: @Klaus Gütter, Thank you very much

Comment: @ Manish Tiwari, Thanks too.

Comment: @Ken please close this question by marking answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ToList() Method.

```
List1.Where(d => List2.Select(x => x.FileName).Contains(d.FileName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `ToList<FileModel>();`

```
List1.Where(x => List2.Select(y => y.FileName).Contains(x.FileName)).ToList<FileModel>();
```